# Python/Cython foo.py --> foo.so

Tags: python, cython

Simple question google couldnt answer:

I am using Cython to convert parts of my library to extension modules using the easycython script. When doing so I have essentially a foo.so and foo.py file in the same folder. Now if I import a class to another file will python automatically use the foo.so or will I have to rename the foo.py so that python is forced to use the foo.so?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

found an answer @ http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html

Pyximport

Cython is a compiler. Therefore it is natural that people tend to go through an edit/compile/test cycle with Cython modules. pyximport simplifies this process by executing the “compile” step at need during import. For instance, if you write a Cython module called foo.pyx, with Pyximport you can import it in a regular Python module like this:

import pyximport; pyximport.install()
import foo

Doing so will result in the compilation of foo.pyx (with appropriate exceptions if it has an error in it).

Comment: That same section also warns: `Note that it is not recommended to let pyximport build code on end user side as it hooks into their import system. The best way to cater for end users is to provide pre-built binary packages in the wheel packaging format.`. Pyximport is to accelerate development, not for use in shipping code.

Answer (score 0):

The `.so` needs to be installed as an extension module for it to be used correctly. If importing from a local directory, the `.py` will override.

It depends what the `setup.py` is installing if that will also be the case when the module is installed.

In short, a `setup.py` for extension code should include at least:

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("foo.py")
)
```

See [documentation](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#basic-setup-py).